Problema al momento de la instalacion de android studio
Tengo un problema con la descarga de los componentes del android studio ya que algunos si se descargan peor luego para la descarga o marca error, y en el momento en que intento iniciar nuevamente no resume la descarga o simplemente se queda quieto por horas y ni siquiera inicia e intendado desintalar y volver a instalar e incluso borras los ajuste del usuario la momento de la desinstalacion y nada, anexo imagenes del problema[

Previamente tenías otra versión de Android Studio verdad? Que versión tratas de instalar?

Veo que se descargan e instalan otros componentes sin problema, si no pude instalar "Intel Atom x86 system image", elimina caché de android studio y reinicia, después de esto, trata nuevamente de realizar la instalación.

Aunque desinstales e instales nuevamente tendrás el problema porque se tienen archivos en caché que provocan falló al instalar la imagen.
